# How to deploy VB.Net using Crystal Report on a PC that has Sage 300 installed?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, sage-300

I'm having issues installing an in-house application (VB.Net) we are making in Visual Studio 2022 with Crystal Reports SP32 on a pc that has Sage 300 2020 v6.7.0.80.

In the setup, we have included the Merge Module (CRRuntime_13_0_32.msm) in the setup. If we install this on a pc that does not have Sage 300, everything works good. The problem is when we installed it on the machine that has Sage 300, it caused Sage to stop working since they are also using Crystal Reports but of a different version. If we omit the Merge Module for Crystal, than our in-house application does not work when we try to open a Crystal Report in the application.  Our in-house application is independent of Sage and does not interact with it.

How do we make a setup for a VB.Net application using Crystal Report without interfering with Sage 300?

We have trying including Crystal Report Merge Module in the Setup for our application. It makes Sage 300 not work after. We have tried excluding the Crystal Report Merge Module from our setup. Sage 300 works but then our application that uses Crystal Report does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend cross-posting this question onto the SAP and Sage 300 support forums.  If you need a work-around until a better solution is found, you could create a VM on the computers and install the new VB.Net app on the VM without Sage 300 installed.  Or you could look into making the app web-based or run it on a terminal server.  Sorry I can't offer much else to help.

Comment: @R.McMillan Thanks for the info. I have already posted my question on SAP and Sage support forums before posting on here. We are already using a terminal server, but was hoping to avoid having users connect to 2 different PCs if possible. And web-based app is not feasible right now.